# Is there a way to make an image show up when you hover over a link?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Questions are often well-served by embedding images. For example, many Dominion questions benefit from showing a picture of the card(s) in question ([example](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/proper-use-of-dominion-card-upgrade)).

However, sometimes it would be awkward and unhelpful to show a picture of every card listed in a question or answer ([this Dominion answer is a good example](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/proper-use-of-dominion-card-upgrade/1637#1637)).

In a question or answer, is there a way to link to an image such that the image shows up when someone hovers of the link, but otherwise just displays as a word and link?

Comment: This would also be great for Magic: The Gathering rules questions.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question.  I guess from the lack of answers that there isn't yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been well over a year, but I'm going to have to [status-decline](/questions/tagged/status-decline) this due to one major issue:

There's no officially supported Dominion card index. The best one we could find is the [Diehrstraits](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/) encyclopedia, but that's not officially supported by the makers of the game. We can't use that to create an SE-endorsed auto-linker like we have for MTG.

As for the pop-up hover window, since we can't autolink (and thus, can't automatically grab an image) you'll have to make do with altering an existing jsfiddle script for MTG to use the Dominion index I linked above. However, bear in mind: if the load gets to be too large, they might start blocking that script!

Comment: I don't get this answer. The question doesn't state that there has to be a card repository, or that this is Dominion specific. Just a way to include an image that is only shown on mouseover.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available for [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) card links. I've written [HoverCard, a userscript](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1459/15823) that does this for you.