# HoverCard, a userscript for MTG card link tooltips

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering, userscript

I've created a userscript that shows a tooltip for any links that start with:

```
http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx
```

It works with both `name` and with `multiverseid` in the query string.

## [HoverCard: BoardGames.SE MTG Gatherer Card Link Rollover](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/18720-hovercard-boardgames-se-mtg-gatherer-card-link-rollover/code)

- Chrome users will need [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).
- Firefox users will need [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

It will display a tooltip centered under the hyperlink. If there isn't enough room to display it under the link, it will display it above instead. If the link spans multiple lines, the tooltip will snap to the far left under the lowest line.

After enabling the userscript, reload this page and test it for yourself:

- `single word` [Fumigate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFumigate%5d)
- `multiple words` [Cataclysmic Gearhulk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCataclysmic%20Gearhulk%5d)
- `hyphen` [Long-Finned Skywhale](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLong-Finned%20Skywhale%5d)
- `comma` [Chandra, Torch of Defiance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Torch%20of%20Defiance%5d)
- `apostrophe` [Nissa, Nature's Artisan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNissa%2c%5d%2b%5bNature%27s%5d%2b%5bArtisan%5d)
- `double quote (")` [Kongming, "Sleeping Dragon"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKongming%2c%20%22Sleeping%20Dragon%22%5d)
- `aether (Æ)` [Æther Tradewinds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5b%c3%86ther%20Tradewinds%5d)
- `exclamation` [Framed!](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFramed!%5d)
- `periods and brackets` [B.F.M. (Big Furry Monster)](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bB.F.M.%20(Big%20Furry%20Monster)%5d)
- `accent` [Ring of Ma'rûf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRing%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bMa%27r%c3%bbf%5d)
- `underscore` [_____](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5b_____%5d)

Ampersands (&), slashes (/) and colons (:) are broken when used with `[mtg:]` MarkDown. You must use `multiverseid`:

- `[mtg:R&D's Secret Lair]` [R&D's Secret Lair](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bR%5d%2b%5bD%27s%5d%2b%5bSecret%5d%2b%5bLair%5d)
- `.aspx?multiverseid=73967` [R&D's Secret Lair](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=73967)

---

[image: HoverCard]

Comment: Gatherer doesn't seem to like https calls, so the script breaks on a secure connection. I added an explicit http: to the imageUrl and that makes the script work, but that introduces a mixed-content warning.

Comment: @MichaelSnook Thanks for the feedback. Can you link an example question where this happens for you? I'd like to reproduce it so I can think of a way to deal with this.

Comment: Sure, compare https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/how-much-damage-do-i-take-when-i-trample-a-stuffy-doll-that-has-pariah-attached with http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/how-much-damage-do-i-take-when-i-trample-a-stuffy-doll-that-has-pariah-attached -- it works with the second page but not the first.

Comment: I did some debugging, the issue is that if you use https for stack exchange, the user script defaults to https for the gatherer search as well, but gatherer doesn't answer.

Comment: @MichaelSnook That's correct. I can't build a way around this. Since Wizards.com doesn't provide the card API on HTTPS, I will have to force it on HTTP. If it causes your browser to spasm over mixed-content, that is normal behavior. Thanks for reporting :)

Comment: I'm clicking card links then remembering I don't have to anymore. Can I just thank you again for making this? It's *so* good.

Comment: I'm getting Javascript errors using this, around the value of the selector. What is the "i" at the end of the href filter? 'a[href*="://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp" i]'

Comment: `i` makes the selector case-insensitive. It's a [CSS4 selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-case). It's [not supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-case-insensitive) yet.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen that. I'm using an up-to-date Chrome though and it's giving me an unrecognized expression error in jQuery. Here's a simple-case Fiddle showing the same thing: https://jsfiddle.net/6e2ezdud/

Comment: @GendoIkari I'm also getting errors. It seems like the `i` directive is no longer working in Chrome, but I'm chalking this up to Chrome (because it's still valid CSS4). I also still need to update the script with doppelgreener's bug below. I'll write an update this week.

Comment: Cool thanks. I hadn't known about this until today, but look forward to using it!

Comment: Looks like a jQuery support thing. Works for selectors in general in Chrome and Firefox, but gives that error in both when using it as a filter in an 'on()' method.

Comment: @GendoIkari Then something recently changed, because this was not broken before. I'll make case-sensitivity optional when I write the update, but if somebody writes `.../pages/card/details.aspx` instead of `.../Pages/Card/Details.aspx` HoverCard won't work because jQuery will match it case-sensitively.

Comment: Just updated to v1.0.6. It no longer uses `[... i]` so it shouldn't break anymore. Also I added support for Search urls and I noticed there was a Handler url so I added those two for matching.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Lion's Eye Diamond isn't working (http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32665/why-isnt-selvala-explorer-returneds-ability-instant-speed); though Sphinx's Revelation in this thread is...

Comment: Lion's Eye Diamond-like cards are fixed in v1.0.8. Please upgrade.

Comment: FWIW, my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script now [also includes this feature.](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1673)

Comment: The tampermonkey script doesn't appear to be working anymore...

Comment: It appears it's no longer `meta.boardgames.se.com` but `boardgames.meta.se.com`.

Comment: Additionally, it seems that Chrome no longer allows loading HTTP resources on a HTTPS site. So it's forcing the image url to `https://`, which doesn't work on the Gatherer site. I think that effectively killed this userscript.

Comment: @MarcDingena I want to update this to use Scryfall's API which is HTTPS. Is this on Github or another repository where I could contribute to it? Alternately I could upload it to my own userscript repository (effectively taking ownership of version 2) if you're okay with me doing that.

Comment: @doppelgreener Please feel free to contribute to https://github.com/mdingena/HoverCard

Comment: @MarcDingena I have done so. :)

Comment: The greasyfork script isn't updated yet with those changes. Should we be fetching the script directly from the Github raw file (https://github.com/mdingena/HoverCard/raw/master/hovercard.user.js)?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to add authors to GreasyFork scripts? Can you set up GreasyFork to pull from GitHub?

Comment: There's no metadata for authors on userscripts, AFAICT. I've moved most of my userscripts to Github just to keep things in one place instead of two, and plan to migrate my mana symbols userscript over now that I realise it's not there already. (I could share the migration procedure if you want to do that.)