# all-purpose mouseover images

Tags: feature-request

[This request](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/491/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-image-show-up-when-you-hover-over-a-link) has been [status-declined](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) because it was scoped as a way to show only Dominion cards. That's not what I'm looking for.

Then there's [this user script](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/hovercard-a-userscript-for-mtg-card-link-tooltips) that works only for MtG cards. That's not what I'm looking for either, I want to be able to mouseover any image.

What I'd like to be able to do, is to include images in a post (same way we do already, using imgur), except then hide the images behind a mouseover.

This can be used for Dominion, Smash Up, Yu-gi-oh, Pokémon, Catan, Stone Age, Fluxx... anything with cards. Experienced players won't need this information as they know the cards, so including them takes up unnecessary space.

**For example**

Right now we have a way of embedding images, using this syntax:

```
[![Monopoly Money][3]][3]

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiWePm.jpg
```

That becomes:
[image: Monopoly Money]

Also we have a way of embedding hyperlinks, that works like this:

```
[Monopoly Money][3]
```

That becomes this:
[Monopoly Money](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiWePm.jpg)

I guess what I want, would look exactly like the [Monopoly Money](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiWePm.jpg) hyperlink, only if you hover your mouse over the hyperlink it shows you the picture without having to click on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make an image show up when you hover over a link?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/491/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-image-show-up-when-you-hover-over-a-link) Dominion was just an example in the other question. You appear to be asking for the same thing.

Comment: @Rainbolt I know. But the other question was misinterpreted and thereby declined so I made one that is more clear.

Comment: One issue I can see that was brought up on the other question is for many of those games there might not be an official source of images that we are allowed to use. And if there isn't one of those it might be a lot of work collecting the images (especially for games like Yu-gi-oh and Pokemon that have thousands of cards), it would also bring up questions of copyright and are we allowed to use those images.

Comment: @diego You don't need an official source of images. If I understand correctly, you will provide the image link when you write a post, and it will become a hover-over link. For example, something like `[my image](https:www.foo.com/image.jpg)` would become a hover-over link. It doesn't matter whether image.jpg is "official".

Comment: @diego I think what you're addressing is a problem with all images on the SE network. The process of searching for and uploading images does not change with this added feature, only the way the image is displayed inside a question or answer.

Comment: @Rainbolt I don't know how to make it any more clear. I started the question with "I'm not looking for X" so if people still think I'm looking for X they need to read.

Comment: @freekvd Maybe you could use a real example, as I did in my previous comment?

Comment: @Rainbolt Something like that I could see using, I was reading the request as more like the current autocard functionality so you would have something like `[dominion:Village]`

Comment: @diego this is not about autocard functionality, that's been status:declined in the question I'm linking to.

Comment: I'd like to point out that in the case of Magic: the Gathering, a link to the card isn't just a link to an image; it's a link to a page with useful information about the card, including the card text. If you want to link to just a card image for other games, you will lose some utility. For example, recent Yu-Gi-Oh link to wiki pages for their cards. Changing those links to plain images would be a detrimental edit that I would reject.

Comment: @murgatroid99 that's an interesting point. If the feature is added, a discussion about whether or not to enforce its use seems appropriate. I could argue that external links are unreliable on the long run, so hosting our own images has its merits. But that would be for argument's sake as I think you're right about your rejection of these edits.

Comment: I guess Magic has the additional benefit that the autocard links we generate are all but guaranteed to be valid by the game's rules

Comment: I don't understand how this got 3 close votes. That other question got declined for being about Dominion.

Comment: @freekvd I explained why I voted to close in my very first comment. You basically responded that you know your question is a duplicate, but decided to ask anyway because the existing question was misinterpreted. You could have clarified the older question, flagged it, and made a case to have the status-declined tag removed. But, because you put so much effort into doing it your way, I went ahead and retracted my close vote and voted to close the other one instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chrome extension that will do this for you: [Imagus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imagus/immpkjjlgappgfkkfieppnmlhakdmaab?hl=en). It is also [available for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imagus/).